# How to embed custom media player in facebook stories (js/firame)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, media-player, embed

We have built a custom media player (https://acorn.athena.ai/) that we want to embed directly into facebook stories. Our embedding currently works via iframe, as our player is entirely JS/CSS/HTML.

Is there a way to embed an iframe?

Looking at the some Open Graph docs on video
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#video), it appears that custom video players in flash can be loaded (specifying `og:video:type` as `application/x-shockwave-flash`), but it says nothing about non-flash custom players.

Comment: Sorry i don't have Facebook (use to :) ), but I'm sure i can help you. can you deploy your media player in app section of Facebook? or you really want it to be in Facebook stories? cause if you create app for Facebook and just call your page (your hosted player, on your hosting server), it would work fine.the reason I'm saying that cause stories don't support some external functionalities (last time i checked)

Answer (score 0):

You are right you need to add the og:video meta attributes, but you can specify it to what you want - it don't need to be flash :)

Take a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#propertytypes-video this gives you an example of what is needed.

Like they also write, then its also import to add the `og:video:secure_url` for users that uses facebook on a HTTPS.

For you situation I would just specify the video to the html page you have the video on, and then specify the type as text/html.

Like this example taking from the above link:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://secure.example.com/awesome-framed.html">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
```